# Copy specific array elements to an existing object (overwrite)

Tags: javascript

I have the following objects

```
var obj1 = 
[
    {
        "id": 1373744172,
        "name": "Run",
        "distance": 6051.8,
        "date": "2018-01-24T16:43:09Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 1370355715,
        "name": "Swim",
        "distance": 1043,
        "date": "2018-01-22T21:10:28Z",
    }
]

var dest = 
[
    {title: "Placeholder", body: "1900-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
]
```

I am trying to overwrite the dest based on obj1, so I should end up with

```
[
    {title: "Run", body: "2018-01-24T16:43:09Z"},
    {title: "Swim", body: "2018-01-22T21:10:28Z"}
]
```

I've looked at Object.assign, and for-in loops, but I've not yet figured out the right approach.  e.g.

```js
var obj1 = 
[
    {
        "id": 1373744172,
        "name": "Run",
        "distance": 6051.8,
        "date": "2018-01-24T16:43:09Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 1370355715,
        "name": "Swim",
        "distance": 1043,
        "date": "2018-01-22T21:10:28Z",
    }
]

var dest = 
[
    {title: "Placeholder", body: "1900-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
]

Object.assign(dest, {title: obj1.name, body: obj1.date});

console.log(JSON.stringify(dest));
```

I'm sure this must have been asked and answered before, but I don't seem to be searching with the right terms!

Comment: *"e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/y9oL42wr/"* Put the code **in** the question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question (and somtimes its answers, probably not here) useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you really want to change the array referenced by `dest`, or do you want a new array? (In the former case other references to the old array would see the updates; in the latter they wouldn't.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder question updated, and link saved, thank you.

Comment: @Richard yes I do want to update `dest`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `Object.assign`, use `array.prototype.map` to transform each element of your array:

```js
var obj1 = 
[
    {
        "id": 1373744172,
        "name": "Run",
        "distance": 6051.8,
        "date": "2018-01-24T16:43:09Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 1370355715,
        "name": "Swim",
        "distance": 1043,
        "date": "2018-01-22T21:10:28Z",
    }
];

var dest = obj1.map(e => ({title: e.name , body: e.date}));

console.log(dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same array instance (as clarified in the comments) [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) can be used, combined with `Array.map` to convert the new elements. But splice takes the new elements as additional parameters, so need to be a little clever about calling `splice`:

```
let args = [0, dest.length].concat(obj1.map(e=>({title: e.name, body: e.date})));
dest.splice.apply(dest, args);
```